# How do I replace a gradle module dependency with a jar?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-project build and one or more sub-projects have a dependency on a broken module. I would like to replace the module dependency with a dependency on a local JAR file.

I've tried the following (which I didn't really expect to work), but beyond this am at a bit of a loss:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()

        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == "com.android.support" && details.requested.name == "support-v4") {
                details.useTarget("lib/android-support-v4-fixed.jar")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I replace a module dependency in a subproject with a dependency on a file (i.e. JAR)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the end I crawled through a lot of documentation and was able to achieve what I wanted quite simply.

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/support-v4.jar')
}
```

The above will exclude a maven dependency for all modules (works fine with libraries etc.), in this case we've excluded the Android support library. Then I simply add my own support library (with several bug fixes) as a regular jar dependency.

Comment: This answer deserves an award for being to the point.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by adding local repository like this:

```
configure(allprojects) {
    repositories {                                                                                                         
      maven {
          url "../repo"  // this is relative to subproject, so assumes all subprojects are in the same folder
      }
      
      // ... other repositories

}
```

The fixed jar should be put to repo dir using mvn folder structure.
For you case two files should be added to `repo/com/android/support/support-v4/r6-fixed`:

```
support-v4-r6-fixed.jar
support-v4-r6-fixed.pom
```

Note: files should be named like `<artifactId>-<version>.<ext>` and this should match values in pom.

The pom should be a valid pom meta with content like (create it using existing pom for broken version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                 
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>r6-fixed</version>
    </project>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But note - you'll need to place your files at _repo/com/android/support/support-v4/_**r6-fixed**_/_ for the described case

Comment: This is an excellent solution, because it is the only answer that keeps the transitive dependencies of the artifact (if they are specified in the pom).

Answer (score 0):

Create a FlatDir repository and put your jar there.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the awesome [solution from Roman Konoval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701500/2300102) in kotlin gradle build files, you need to specify the path as an URI, example:

```
configure(allprojects) {
  repositories {                                                                                                         
    maven {
      url = uri("../repo")  // this is relative to subproject, so assumes all subprojects are in the same folder
   }
  
   // ... other repositories
}
```